# Shade the surface and contour parts

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, mplot3d

I want to shade the surface and the contours of a specific function based on some constraint in the domain of the function. So far I have the following and I want to improve it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.axes(projection="3d")
xdata = np.linspace(-3, 3, 20000)
ydata = np.linspace(-3, 3, 20000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xdata, ydata)

Z1 = X ** 2 + Y ** 2
Z2 = Z1.copy()
Z3 = Z1.copy()
Z1[np.multiply(X, Y) > 3] = np.nan 
Z2[np.multiply(X, Y) <= 3] = np.nan
Z3[np.multiply(X, Y) == 3] = np.nan

ax3d = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax3d.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1,  cmap='Greys', antialiased=True, vmin=-np.nanmin(Z1), vmax=np.nanmax(Z1))
ax3d.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2, cmap='YlGnBu', antialiased=True, vmin=-np.nanmin(Z2), vmax=np.nanmax(Z2))

ax3d.contourf(X, Y, Z1, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap='Greys')
ax3d.contourf(X, Y, Z2, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap='Greys')

ax3d.set_title('Surface Plot in Matplotlib')
ax3d.set_xlabel('X')
ax3d.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3d.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Could you please someone help to solve the following problems:

1. The surface is over-imposed by the contour surface.
2. There are some gaps in the surface.
3. The contours of the two constraints are not continuous.
4. Is it possible to plot a line in the border of the two surfaces and contours?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @JohanC thanks for you interest. Unfortunately, I haven't work with these concepts before. Is it possible to provide an example for the surface in the post?

Answer (score 2):

The code below makes the following changes:

- creating a custom colormap combining the two existing colormaps
- using a `TwoSlopeNorm` to have the separation at `z=3`
- setting `antialiased=False` (otherwise matplotlib creates a plot of antialiased lines instead of polygons)
- `xdata` and `ydata` with 300 steps
- using `rstride=1, cstride=1` so every x and every y will be considered; this makes the surface smoother (but takes more time)
- calling `plt.axes(...)` only once to prevent a dummy subplot
- calling `contourf` before `plot_surface`; due to the [painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm), matplotlib [only minimally supports 3D overlaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm, ListedColormap
import numpy as np

xdata = np.linspace(-3, 3, 300)
ydata = np.linspace(-3, 3, 300)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xdata, ydata)

Z1 = X ** 2 + Y ** 2

cmap1 = plt.get_cmap('Greys')
cmap2 = plt.get_cmap('YlGnBu')
cmap = ListedColormap(np.r_[cmap1(np.linspace(0, 1, 128)), cmap2(np.linspace(0, 1, 128))])
norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=np.nanmin(Z1), vmax=np.nanmax(Z1), vcenter=3)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax3d = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax3d.contourf(X, Y, Z1, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax3d.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1, cmap=cmap, antialiased=False, norm=norm, rstride=1, cstride=1)

ax3d.set_title('Surface Plot in Matplotlib')
ax3d.set_xlabel('X')
ax3d.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3d.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot_surface with custom colormap and finer grid]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As fa as I understand, you create two `cmap`s concatenate them and center them at value 3. I am trying to integrate you example in my case but I am not getting a similar result to that in my post. Could you please provide some additional detains on how we can adjust your example to use the function domain constraints in my post?

Comment: Which are the differences between your post and your actual function domain constraints?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you question. What confuses me is that in you post, the color map is centered in some fixed value, but in my case, these values is changing some how based on the constraints imposed in in the domain variables. What I am trying is to combine these two. Is it possible to elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: The value chosen is `3`, just as in your example.   If you want to only use part of the colormaps, you could restrict the ranges in the `np.linspace(0,1,...)`. E.g. `cmap = ListedColormap(np.r_[cmap1(np.linspace(0, 0.8, 128)), cmap2(np.linspace(0.3, 1, 128))])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
xdata = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
ydata = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xdata, ydata)

Z1 = X ** 2 + Y ** 2
Z2 = Z1.copy()
Z3 = Z1.copy()

Z2[np.multiply(X, Y) <= 3] = np.nan
Z3[np.multiply(X, Y) == 3] = np.nan


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax3d = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax3d.contourf(X, Y, Z1, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap='Greys')
ax3d.contourf(X, Y, Z2, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap='YlGnBu')


ax3d.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1,  cmap='Greys', antialiased=True, vmin=-np.nanmin(Z1), vmax=np.nanmax(Z1), alpha=.5)
ax3d.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2, cmap='YlGnBu', antialiased=True, vmin=-np.nanmin(Z2), vmax=np.nanmax(Z2), alpha=.5)

ax3d.set_title('Surface Plot in Matplotlib')
ax3d.set_xlabel('X')
ax3d.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3d.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```